# Basic JavaScript/jQuery: how to return variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, return

I've had a look around & can't see an answer to this, I'm a bit of a novice with JS so bear with me!

I'm working on a small site design which uses the [Coda style slider from jQuery4Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/).
Part of the design is to have an underscore prefixed to the active navigation link. So I've attempted to by creating a variable and then updating the existing function in the JS for the slider. Now this works:

```
var activeLink = $('#nav li a.selected').text();

// handle nav selection
function selectNav() {
    $(this)
        .parents('ul:first')
            .find('a')
                .removeClass('selected')
                .text(activeLink) //this ensures the non-active link has no underscore
            .end()
        .end()
        .addClass('selected')
        .text("_" + activeLink); //this adds the underscore to the active link
}
```

**The problem I have is that this makes every link the original active link** I believe the varible isn't updated to display the new `a.selected`. So If my first active link was "Item One", I end up having the whole list displaying "Item One" for every `li`

**Please can someone tell me how to achieve this,as I am unsure how to proceed**.

Thanks in advance, please let me know if I can give any additional information.

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you set `activeLink` to "Item One" and then give it to every element of `ul:first a`. That's what your code does.

Instead of this variable, consider dynamically adjusting the existing value of each element, using the fact that [you can give `.text()` a function](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
// handle nav selection
function selectNav() {
    $(this)
        .parents('ul:first')
            .find('a')
                .removeClass('selected')
                .text(function(index, text) {
                    return text.replace(/^_/, '');
                }) //this ensures the non-active link has no underscore
            .end()
        .end()
        .addClass('selected')
        .text(function(index, text) {
            return "_" + text;
        }); //this adds the underscore to the active link
}
```

<sup>Untested. May contain bugs.</sup>

Comment: Hey, sorry about the delay in my response! Thanks for the suggestion will try this out asap! The concept makes sense (which is reassuring for me!!). Thanks again

Comment: Just tried out the code you suggested Tomalak & it seems to work fine (full testing pending)! Thanks a lot.

One thing I'm struggling to understand is the return within the function, specifically 'text.replace(/^_/, '');'

But I'm sure upon further reading it will come to me. Thanks again - much appreciated!!!

Comment: @Sheixt: No problem. What I'm returning is the result of the `String.replace(<regex>, <replacement>)` function, replacing instances of `_` found at the start of the string (`^`) with the empty string `''`; that is, removing a single leading underscore if it's there.

Comment: you legend! Thanks for spelling it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are currect, by saving activeLink in the 1st line, you have saved the current selected li.

Just move the "var activeLink....." inside the function selectNav().

Comment: He still assigns that one variable to _every_ link. Changing its value doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am confused with your question , but to my best I think this will help

```
function selectNav() {
    $(this)
        .parent('li')
        .find('a')
        .addClass('selected')
        .text("_" + activeLink)
        .parent('li')
        .siblings('li')
        .find('a')
        .removeClass('selected')
        .text(activeLink)

}
```

I hope this helps